# How to delete specific import from each file in application?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In eclipse, how can I delete a specific import from each file in a package?

For example, I need to remove the following from an entire package:

```
import android.R;
```

I am NOT asking how to remove unused imports, just how to remove a specific line of code..in this case, an import.

Comment: You can run the Eclipse "Optimize imports" tool on a class, a package, or your whole project (and it's the same for the formatting tool). The quick way to achieve what you want is to select the package and to use the shortcut "Ctrl + Shift + O".

Comment: Press `Ctrl+H` and then replace `import android.R;` with nothing in all project..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Select the package in your *Package Explorer View*.
- Choose Menu->Search->File
- in the dialog set *Containing text* to `import android.R;` and *File name patterns* to `*.java`
- for *Scope* - choose "Selected resources"
- Click on *Replace*
- The Search view will show all matches and you get a new dialog where you'll have to enter the replacement (leave it empty in your case)

Note, that this is *not* a refactoring. Replacing text may lead to dozens of compiletime errors, that have to be fixed manually.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions->Configure...

You can configure the removal of unused imports when saving from the Unnecessary Code tab.

Adding imports would normally be done as you are writing the code otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: Try this also..  http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcodestyle%2Fref-preferences-organize-imports.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
ctrl-Shift-O-I  is the shortcut to organize import in a particular file in eclipse..
```

Also you can right the entire package and select the Organize Import option available there to rmove unsed imports in entire package.

Comment: Sorry, but I think I guided you for remove unused imports,, you can use replace all text options from the Menu->Search->File editor to replace or remove some  lines of codes in entire package